# Get user model from different database

Tags: adonis.js

I need to implement JWT authentication for an adonis app, but the user data will be stored on another database and the token generated by an existing API.

From the [docs](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/authentication#_config), configuring the database serializer only allows setting the table and field names, which wouldn't work for retrieving user data from a different database.

Is it possible to connect to multiple databases and then specify from which one the user data should be fetched when the JWT is received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to change db connection but I don't think it's possible with `auth` object. I think you need to implement your own JWT validation system.

**Here is some information that might help you do so:**

### Change db connection

Doc: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/database#_multiple_connections

**!** Only with `Database` object. Not working with [Lucid](https://forum.adonisjs.com/t/lucid-database-change-database-when-running-query/776/4)

```js
await Database.connection('mysql') // Change connection (from your "config/database.js" file)
```

### Get header data from `request`

Doc: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/request#_headers

```js
var auth = request.header('authorization') // jwt token
```

### Validate JWT

The official documentation does not provide any information on the jwt validation method.

[Adonis `Auth` github repository](https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-auth)

Here is the code specific to JWT token : https://github.com/adonisjs/adonis-auth/blob/develop/src/Schemes/Jwt.js

### Advanced help

A better answer/help can be provided on :

Official forum : https://forum.adonisjs.com/

Discord : https://discordapp.com/invite/vDcEjq6

or create an issue on GitHub